# Confusion Regarding Character Polynomials and Dimensions of Irreducible Representations in the Symmetric Group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

I am trying to use the [Garsia–Goupil formula](http://www.combinatorics.org/Volume_16/Abstracts/v16i2r19.html).
Fundamentally, the character polynomial satisfies
$$
\chi^{(n-|\mu|, \mu)}_{1^{a_1} 2^{a_2} \cdots} = q_\mu(a_1, a_2, \ldots) \equiv q_\mu(1^{a_1} 2^{a_2} \cdots).
$$
Given this notation, I can only presume that $q_\mu$ *does not* depend on $n$? I guess it only really makes sense to look at $\chi^\lambda_\sigma$ if both have parts summing to $n$? (Here is a precursor to my confusion.)

I'm doing it for $\ell$-cycles, ie $a_1 = n-\ell$, $a_\ell = 1$ and $a_i = 0$ for $i \notin \{1, \ell\}$.
Then, the main result of that paper says that
$$
q_\mu(1^{n-\ell} \ell^1)
=
q_\mu(1^{n-\ell})
+
\sum_{\xi \in BS(\ell, \mu)}
q_{\mu \setminus \xi}(1^{n-\ell}),
$$
where $BS(\ell, \mu)$ is the set of border-strip tableaux in $\mu$ of length $\ell$. Note that if $k = |\mu| < \ell$, then $BS(\ell, \mu) = \emptyset$. In their notation, we only have $j = 1$ as $x_\ell = 1$; this somewhat simplifies the inner sum.

> Main question: how do I evaluate these character polynomials on the right-hand side, probably in terms of dimensions $d_{\lambda'}$ for some $\lambda'$?

I'm rather confused as how to do this. I do have a citation for it (see below), but I'm a little unsure on the legitimacy of it. I want to make sure I'm doing everything completely above board!

I'm not really sure what it means to say that
$$
q_\mu(1^{n-\ell})
=
\chi^{(n-\ell-|\mu|, \mu)}_{(1^{n-\ell})}.
$$
We assume that $\mu_1 \le n - |\mu|$, ie $\mu$ is genuinely a shape $\lambda$ without its first row. But what if $n-\ell-|\mu| < \mu_1$? Or, even worse, what if $n - \ell - |\mu| < 0$?

Garsia–Goupil do mention what to do when the 'exponent' partition isn't correctly ordered. They say about rearranging parts and changing the sign. I am only interested in the absolute value of these---I'm going to apply the triangle inequality across the whole sum to bound $|q_\mu(1^{n-\ell} \ell^1)|$. So I don't mind if the sign changes.

The paper by [Bernstein](https://doi.org/10.1214/18-EJP140) which, on close analysis, turns out to have a number of mistakes, simply claims (p13) that
$$ \textstyle
q_\mu(1^{n-\ell})
=
d_{(n-\ell-|\mu|, \mu)}
\le
\binom{n-\ell}{|\mu|}
d_\mu.
$$
I don't really see how to justify this, or what it really even means in the cases I just outlined. The fact that her paper has a number of other mistakes, ranging from minor to actually fairly major, makes me hesitant to just apply it.
Moreover, can I just do the same when replacing $\mu$ with $\mu \setminus \xi$, ie $\mu$ without its $\xi$-border-strip?